# Encrypt Data using Public Key

Tags: php, encryption-asymmetric

```
$key = file_get_contents('http://keyserver.pramberger.at/pks/lookup?op=get&search=uid');
```

after getting public key in `'$key'` variable i need to encrypt the data using this public key.
the key must be start with ----Begin pgp block ---to end pgp block----.
How this can be done in php?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this article about [Encryption and Decryption using PHP and GnuPG](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1265) (found via Google) helps you.

And there is also a [PHP module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php) to interact with GnuPG.

Afaik, GPG is compatible with PGP.