# equivalent method of gnupg.GPG and gpg.import_keys(pub_key).summary() in php

Tags: php, security, encryption

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome="/tmp/foldername", verbose=True)
print "Import the Key :", gpg.import_keys(pub_key).summary()

this two lines of code gives me public key exract which i further used in encryption.
i need to get the equivalent metods in php .

Comment: In this question really different from your first one?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460941/encrypt-data-using-public-key

Comment: it is a linked one ,here i eager to know is there any php equivalent method to these python method

Comment: Oh it is python? Didn't know that... Anyway the answers to the other questions should give you an answer to this: Either use it from commandline or have a look which methods are offered by the PHP GPG module.

Answer (score 0):

PHP GPG functions are described in the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php)